# $\int_{0}^{\frac\pi{2}} cos(x)^6\,dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

I need to solve
$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos^6xdx$ 
I tried to use $cos(3x)=4\cos^3x-3\cos x$ but not succeeded

Comment: For definite integral, there is a formula http://arcmathblog.blogspot.com/2014/11/walliss-formula-for-integrals-of-powers.html which is easily proven using integration by parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use that $$\cos^6(x)=\frac{1}{32} (15 \cos (2 x)+6 \cos (4 x)+\cos (6 x)+10)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$2I=\int_0^{\pi/2}(\cos^6x+\sin^6x)dx$$

Now $c^6+s^6=(c^2+s^2)^3-3c^2s^2(c^2+s^2)=1-\dfrac{3(2cs)^2}4$

$$8I=\int_0^{\pi/2}(4-3\sin^22x)dx$$

$$16I=\int_0^{\pi/2}(8-3(1-\cos4x))dx=?$$